# GitHub: Как настроить url адрес для многостраничного сайта?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

Есть 3-страничный сайт на Github Pages. Стандартный адрес такой: https://alexanderokhotnichenko.github.io/react-cat-energy-landing/ (в конце название репозитории). При попытки перейти на другую страницу к примеру **КАТАЛОГ ПРОДУКЦИИ** у меня заменяется в конце url адреса на https://alexanderokhotnichenko.github.io/catallog. То-есть уберается название репозитории и заменяется на ***catallog***. И из-за этого пол сайта не работает. Что делать и как исправить?

Меню с ссылка для переходов между страница:

```
<ul className={ styles.menu__list }>
   <Link onClick={onCloseMenu} to="/">главная</Link>
   <Link onClick={onCloseMenu} to="/catallog">каталог продукции</Link>
   <Link onClick={onCloseMenu} to="/form">подбор программы</Link>
</ul>
```

Ссылка на репозиторий: https://github.com/AlexanderOkhotnichenko/react-cat-energy-landing

Comment: `То-есть уберается **название репозитории** и заменяется на catallog` `...github.io/catallog`. в качестве названия для репа использующегося в git pages нужно ставить свой логин, тогда оно не будет лезть в формирование пути. ну по крайней мере не должно.

Comment: Я так пробовал с другим репозиторией. Не работает